# Spring data - search Documents by search string and two parameters

Tags: mongodb, spring-data

I will search workingBook documents in my mongoDB database by a search string and two parameters: project and tenant.
Is there a possibility to do this?
This is my current Spring data query but it does not work:

```
@Query("{$text : { $search : ?0 } }")
List<WorkingBook> findWorkingBookByProjectAndTenantAndSearchString(final Project project, final Tenant tenant,
        final String searchString);
```

Thats a sample document:

```
db.WorkingBook.find().pretty()
{
"_id" : ObjectId("589f2af42f7a97b95842afc6"),
"_class" : "my.domain.dao.domain.WorkingBook",
"dateTimeFrom" : ISODate("2017-02-11T15:16:33Z"),
"dateTimeUntil" : ISODate("2017-02-11T16:17:33Z"),
"categoryType" : "SERVICE",
"workingText" : "That's a working book text ",
"creationDateTime" : ISODate("2017-02-11T15:17:08.550Z"),
"user" : DBRef("User", ObjectId("5589929b887dc1fdb501cdba")),
"project" : DBRef("Project", ObjectId("5899eb0dbfb41f1382eac15a")),
"tenant" : DBRef("Tenant", ObjectId("58500aed747a6cddb55ba094"))
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have `id` field like below in both `Project` and `Tenant` classes.

```
@Id
private String id;
```

and `DBRef` like below in `WorkingBook`

```
@DBRef
private Project project;

@DBRef
private Tenant tenant;
```

**With `@Query` annotation**

Pass the project and tenant id along with search string.

```
@Query("{$text : { $search : ?0 }, 'project' : ?1, 'tenant' : ?2 }")
List<WorkingBook> findWorkingBookByProjectAndTenantAndSearchString(final String searchString, final String projectId, final String tenantId);
```

**Without `@Query` annotation**

You can define the the below method in repository.

```
List<WorkingBook> findByProjectAndTenant(final TextCriteria searchString, final String projectId, final String tenantId);
```

Calling Code

```
TextCriteria  textCriteria = new TextCriteria().matching(searchString);
List<WorkingBook> workingBookList = workingBookRepository.findByProjectAndTenant(textCriteria, projectId, tenantId);
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring Data does not combine the query from an annotation with a query derived from the method name. So if you want to combine the search query with what would otherwise generated from the name you have to do it yourself and put it in the annotation.

Comment: And how to do this in my case, I'm not clear how to implement, with @Query annotation or ...? Thanks a lot!